# Python Array for error messages

Tags: python, list

Currently I display my errors like this:

**Python API:**

```
errors = {}
errors['message'] = 'Sorry we could not log you in.'
return self.create_response(request, {'errors':[errors]}, HttpUnauthorized)
```

Then in Javascript I display them like this:

```
for (var key in object.data.errors) {
     $scope.errors.push(object.data.errors[key].message);
   }
```

As you can see the javascript loops an array of errors, but in Python if I try to do this:

```
errors = {}
errors['message'] = 'Sorry we could not log you in.'
errors['message'] = 'another error'
return self.create_response(request, {'errors':[errors]}, HttpUnauthorized)
```

because this code only appends the last error and the first will be overwritten.

How can I keep the same principal but in Python allow myself to actually append error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a dict of errors but you're using the same key (`message`) with your two errors. You should make a list of errors instead:

```
errors = []
errors.append('Sorry we could not log you in.')
errors.append('another error')
return self.create_response(request, {'errors': errors}, HttpUnauthorized)
```

and then iterate on this list.

```
for (var key in object.data.errors) {
    $scope.errors.push(object.data.errors[key]); /* .message isn't necessary now */
}
```

If you want to add more information about the error, you can make a list of dict:

```
errors.append({'message': 'Sorry we could not log you in.', 'uid': 42})
errors.append({'message': 'another error', 'uid': 1337})  
# uid parameter is imaginary here, it's just for the example
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example try this.

```
            response = {}
            response['errors'] = []
            response['errors'].append({'message': 'another error message'})
            response['errors'].append({'message': 'Sorry we could not log you in.'})
            return self.create_response(request, response, HttpUnauthorized)
```

This would give you a list of errors that will work with the javascript example you provided. You can also then do something like this:

```
 response['errors'].append({'message': 'Sorry we could not log you in.', 'code', '22'})
```

etc

Comment: @glglgl 'response' oops, fingers to keyboard interface error, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of making `errors` a `dict`? Do you use anything other than the `'message'` value?

In any event, you can just make it a list:

```
errors['message'] = []                                     ## initialise to empty list
errors['message'].append('Sorry we could not log you in.') ## add first error message
errors['message'].append('another error')                  ## add next
```

Comment: this would give me an array of messages, not an array of errors I think.